# Can I mix several threads into one using modules in Wowze?

Tags: wowza

Need to know if it is possible to mix several rtmp threads into one using modules? By Picture-in-Picture type, or simply there is a main stream, and additional streams add sound. It's the mixing that I need so that all the streamers can be heard at the same time.

I need to see if that's possible in principle, so I don't have to spend time on investigating if that's not possible. And what skills does a specialist need to have in order to create a module like this?

Answer (score 0):

Wowza Streaming Engine does not support compositing today (4.8.5), so I would recommend merging the streamings prior to ingesting them as a single source.